# Problems with BarLegend in MatrixPlot

Tags: plotting, legending

I have the following data:

```
TableA = {{5.72, 5.81, 1.13}, {4.81, 5.25, 0.86}, {4.31, 2.88, 
0.73}, {3.98, 2.38, 0.71}, {3.81, 2.33, 0.84}, {2.37, 0.97, 0.74}};
TableB = {{20.2, 5.91, 2.00}, {15.0, 4.37, 1.41}, {12.1, 3.14, 
1.13}, {10.2, 2.59, 1.02}, {9.19, 2.29, 1.08}, {4.90, 1.22, 
0.88}};
```

And I want to create a `MatrixPlot` of these:

```
PlotA3k = 
MatrixPlot[TableA, 
FrameLabel -> {Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(z\), \(i\)]\)", 20], 
 Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(i\)]\)", 20]}, 
PlotLabel -> 
Style["\[CapitalDelta]\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(A\), \(_\)]\)", 22], 
LabelStyle -> Directive[12], 
PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[Automatic], {After, Center}], 
ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
FrameTicks -> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {1, 2, 3}}, 
DataReversed -> {True, False}];
PlotR3k = 
MatrixPlot[TableB, 
FrameLabel -> {Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(z\), \(i\)]\)", 20], 
 Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(i\)]\)", 20]}, 
PlotLabel -> 
Style["\[CapitalDelta]\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(R\), \(_\)]\)", 22], 
LabelStyle -> Directive[12], 
PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[Automatic], {After, Center}], 
ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
FrameTicks -> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {1, 2, 3}}, 
DataReversed -> {True, False}];
```

I have problems with the numbers in the BarLegend.

[image: matrix plots]

I want to have kind of percentage bar, running from the lowest to the maximum value of the data. Also I notice that numbers doesn't appear as decimals.

Comment: Sorry...I forget to change the names on tables..now it should compile

Comment: partly a duplicate of [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21263/color-function-doesnt-span-the-whole-color-range-in-matrixplot)

Comment: and partly a duplicate of [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22727/how-to-set-plotlegend-number-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
PlotA3k = 
 Legended[MatrixPlot[TableA, 
   FrameLabel -> {Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(z\), \(i\)]\)", 20], 
     Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(i\)]\)", 20]}, 
   PlotLabel -> 
    Style["\[CapitalDelta]\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(A\), \(_\)]\)", 22],
   LabelStyle -> Directive[12],
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][
       Rescale[#, {0, 10}, {0, 1}]] &),
   FrameTicks -> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {1, 2, 3}},
   DataReversed -> {True, False}],
  Placed[
   BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 10}},
    LegendLayout -> "Column",
    LegendMargins -> 0],
   {After, Center}]]
```

[image: matrixplot]

[This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22727/how-to-set-plotlegend-number-format) also suggests that the default number format is 'fractions'. So:

```
MatrixPlot[RandomReal[1, {2, 2}], PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: basic matrix plot]

Comment: @AlejandroGuarnizo that's why I think you should use {0,10} rather than Automatic.

Comment: I almost got it..but I'm wondering how I can control the automatic scale. I mean..since for example in  TableB the largest value is about 22..how I can "say" that the LegendBar goes from zero to that value?

Comment: @AlejandroGuarnizo In my answer the legend and the plot are both using {0, 10} to control how the colours are allocated. With {0,10} there are no reds or oranges because there are no values in TableA above 5.8. Use {0,25} if you want.

Comment: Thank you so much @cormullion I got it!!!

Comment: @AlejandroGuarnizo Cool. Explanations are found in the linked posts. (Thanks for the Accept!)

Answer (score 2):

You could also try this approach:

```
MatrixPlot[Rescale@TableA, DataReversed -> {True, False}, Mesh -> All,
  ColorFunctionScaling -> True, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {.5, 1}}, 10, LegendMarkerSize -> 300], 
  PlotLabel -> Style["\[CapitalDelta]\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(R\), \(_\)]\)", 22], 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(z\), \(i\)]\)", 20], 
  Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(i\)]\)", 20]}]]
```

Result:

[image]

You could also use another color function, for instance, `"TemperatureMap"`:

[image]

Comment: I thought he wanted his {1,1} square to be legended as 5.72 - but your scale only goes up to 1...?

Comment: @cormullion I use `Rescale[]` to convert the data for plotting purposes. That's why the scale goes from 0 to 1.